# Реализация на C++ аналога функции openssl_encrypt из php (OpenSSL)

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

Мне в клиент на C++ дают данные с HTTP-сервера, зашифрованные функцией:

`openssl_encrypt($data,'AES-256-CTR','<какой-то $Key>',OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,'<какой-то $InitializationVector>');`

Как реализовать аналогичное кодирование, а также декодирование этих данных на C++ средствами OpenSSL? Я имею ввиду какие функции `libssl` и/или `libcrypto` в какой последовательности должны вызываться для реализации аналогичного шифрования?

*PS: уж простите, с OpenSSL работаю впервые...*

Comment: Посмотрите исходники, а именно как эта функция реализована в PHP. Для AES-CTR в OpenSSL есть функция AES_ctr128_encrypt например...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Вдруг кому пригодится:

**CPP:**

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "stringf.h" // собственная обёртка для операций с файлами под Windows

std::string openssl_encrypt(std::string data, const EVP_CIPHER * mode, unsigned char * key, unsigned char * iv){
    int buf_length, out_length;
    unsigned char *cipher_text = (unsigned char*)malloc(data.length());
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if(!ctx){return "ctx is null";}
    if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, mode, NULL, key, iv)){return "EVP_EncryptInit_ex error";}
    if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, cipher_text, &buf_length, (unsigned char*)data.c_str(), data.length())){return "EVP_EncryptUpdate error";}
    out_length = buf_length;
    if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, cipher_text + buf_length, &buf_length)){return "EVP_EncryptFinal_ex error";}
    out_length += buf_length;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    std::string out(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipher_text), out_length);
    free(cipher_text);
    return out;
}
std::string openssl_decrypt(std::string cipher, const EVP_CIPHER * mode, unsigned char * key, unsigned char * iv){
    int buf_length, out_length;
    unsigned char *data_buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(cipher.length());
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if(!ctx){return "ctx is null";}
    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, mode, NULL, key, iv)){return "EVP_DecryptInit_ex error";}
    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, data_buf, &buf_length, (unsigned char*)cipher.c_str(), cipher.length())){return "EVP_DecryptUpdate error";}
    out_length = buf_length;
    if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, data_buf + buf_length, &buf_length)){return "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex error";}
    out_length += buf_length;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    std::string out(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data_buf), out_length);
    free(data_buf);
    return out;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc > 2){
        unsigned char * key256 = (unsigned char *)argv[1]; // обязательно 32 символа (256 бит)
        unsigned char * iv128 = (unsigned char *)argv[2]; // обязательно 16 символов (128 бит)
        std::string data = "Hello World!";
        std::string cpp_cipher, php_cipher;
        stringf::WriteBufferToFile("D:\\aes.cpp", openssl_encrypt(data, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), key256, iv128));
        stringf::ReadFileToBuffer("D:\\aes.cpp", cpp_cipher);
        stringf::ReadFileToBuffer("D:\\aes.php", php_cipher);
        std::cout << "CPP cipher:\t" << openssl_decrypt(cpp_cipher, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), key256, iv128) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PHP cipher:\t" << openssl_decrypt(php_cipher, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), key256, iv128) << std::endl;
    }
    else{std::cout << "Not enough arguments!\n";}
    return 0;
}
```

**BAT:**

```
test.exe 11112222333344445555666677778888 1111333355557777
pause
```

**PHP** (для двусторонней проверки):

```
<?php
$key256 = '11112222333344445555666677778888';
$iv128 = '1111333355557777';
$data = "Hello World!";
file_put_contents('D:\\aes.php', openssl_encrypt($data,'AES-256-CTR',$key256,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv128));
$cpp = file_get_contents('D:\\aes.cpp');
echo 'CPP cipher decrypted: ';
var_dump(openssl_decrypt($cpp,'AES-256-CTR',$key256,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv128));
```